# Why does Sphinx duplicate images in HTML output directory?

Tags: python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx to generate HTML documentation and have a structure similar to the  following:

```
docs/
├── _static/
├── _templates/
├── guide/
│   ├── index.rst
│   └── image.jpg
├── conf.py
├── index.rst
├── make.bat
└── Makefile
```

I reference `docs/guide/index.rst` from `docs/index.rst` and embed `docs/guide/image.jpg` in `docs/guide/index.rst` using the `image:` directive.

What I notice is that after running `make html`, the `build` directory created has duplicated `image.jpg`, once in a `build/html/_static/` folder, and once in a `build/html/_images/` folder. Is there any reason for this or way to not duplicate the image? It seems that the generated HTML is only referencing the image using the `build/html/_images/` path.

Comment: You need to check if it is sphinx or the theme you use leads to the duplicate images, and then report the issue to sphinx or that theme authors on GitHub. Not much to be discussed here on SO.

Comment: Good point; it looks like default `html_theme` is "alabaster" as set after running the `sphinx-quickstart` command. I'm not sure if this is actually an issue or intended behavior, so it felt right asking on SO before opening an issue with Sphinx. Maybe someone could shed light on the difference between the `_images` and `_static` directories created.

Comment: I gave it a try and `sphinx-rtd-theme` does not generate duplicate images like you described, so I assume this is a `alabaster` only issue. But usually people put `image.jpg` in `docs/guide/_static`.

Comment: Weird—I'm seeing the same behavior after switching to `sphinx-rtd-theme` and moving the image to `/_static`. Will do some more digging and see if I can replicate your results.

Comment: If I put the image in an `_images` folder, then it doesn't copy it over to the `_static` folder in the output directory. This is the case for both `alabaster` and `sphinx-rtd-theme`. I can write this as the answer here, but might be worth opening an issue with sphinx since I don't see this behavior documented.